# Cron - Run every year once at January 1 00:00 or 12.00 am

Tags: node.js, cron

I am using npm i cron to run cron schedule in node.js. I want to run the schedule every start of the year at 12.00 am i.e Jan 1 every year once at 12.00 am . How can I make it run? Anybody can help please.

Comment: [https://crontab.guru/#0_12_1_1_*](https://crontab.guru/#0_12_1_1_*) maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the code below to do this. When the script starts, it will print out the next 10 dates the job will run on:

```
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;

const cronExpression ="0 0 1 JAN *";

const cronJob = new CronJob(
    cronExpression,
    cronFunction
);

function cronFunction() {
    console.log("cronFunction: Running....");
    // Add whatever you wish here...
}

// Print out the next dates the job will run
const nextDates = cronJob.nextDates(10);
console.log("Next dates the job will run on:", nextDates.map(d => d.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")));

cronJob.start();
```

The output should look like so:

```
Next dates the job will run on: [
  '2022-01-01 00:00',
  '2023-01-01 00:00',
  '2024-01-01 00:00',
  '2025-01-01 00:00',
  '2026-01-01 00:00',
  '2027-01-01 00:00',
  '2028-01-01 00:00',
  '2029-01-01 00:00',
  '2030-01-01 00:00',
  '2031-01-01 00:00'
]
```